# Multiprocessing: Python code to call my method with pool.map_async().get() is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing

I am trying to run the below basic example code for multiprocessing in my Jupyter Notebook.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def square(x):
    print('=====> ',x)
    return x * x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    inputs = [0,1,2,3,4]
    outputs_async = pool.map_async(square, inputs)
    print(outputs_async)
    outputs = outputs_async.get(timeout=10)
    print("Output: {}".format(outputs))
```

And i am getting the below as output,

```
<multiprocessing.pool.MapResult object at 0x00000249E3A17188>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f7d558819a08> in <module>
     12     outputs_async = pool.map_async(square, inputs)
     13     print(outputs_async)
---> 14     outputs = outputs_async.get(timeout=10)
     15     print("Output: {}".format(outputs))

~\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    651         self.wait(timeout)
    652         if not self.ready():
--> 653             raise TimeoutError
    654         if self._success:
    655             return self._value

TimeoutError:
```

It looks like that, the code is not calling my **square** method itself.

Please help on how to fix this.

Thanks,

Comment: This issue is related to the way you handle this in Jupyter. If run as a "plain" script it works perfectly - i.e., it is not a Python issue. You should consider adding Jupyter to your question tags

Comment: @DarkKnight, run as a "plain" script means ?

Comment: Running as a plain script would mean running it on the Python interpreter, instead of inside a Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: @SM079 Let's say your code is in a file called foo.py then, from a command line, run: *python foo.py*

Comment: @DarkKnight, yes you are right. it runs as plain script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a work-around, place the code ou want to run in the multiprocessed-workers in a stand alone  ".py" module, a real file, not a notebook cell, in any directory in your "sys.path" - then use it as:

```
import mymodule
...

    outputs_async = pool.map_async(mymodule.square, inputs)
```

The reason it may be broken is that with the Spawn method (the default for multi-processing in Windows and Mac), involves importing all needed modules for the code to run, by using normal Python importing mechanisms - and if the code is in a notebook cell, it can't be imported.

It still *may not work* as the `__main__` module itself is under Jupyter's guard - but it looks like they (Jupyter developers) patched things around enough for it to behave as if it were a plain script - otherwise you would not be getting even your error message as listed above.